# Distance Matrix output

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix

I'm using QGIS 2.18 Las Palmas, and I'm trying to build up a Distance Matrix of a series of points for a Mantel test. Specifically, I have a series of points and I want to calculate the distance of each of them to all the other ones. Now, when I use the 'Distance Matrix' tool in QGIS it gives me a three column table with all the distances, in this way:

InputID,C,254   TargetID,C,254  Distance,C,254
1               1               0
1               2               16.2788206
1               3               19.92485885
1               4               36.138622
1               5               69.23149572

This kind of output file contains all the information I need, but in the wrong format. What I'm looking for is a triangular distance matrix, as I need it as an input file for a Mantel test, like this one:

```
    1           2           3           4           5
```

1       0
2       16.2788206  0
3       19.92485885 23.84674    0
4       36.138622   29.4846735  55.68871    0
5       69.23149572 45.22356    66.254128   78.6542212  0

If it is possible to do this with QGIS, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a programmatic solution, you can do this easily in R with the `dist` function and the `raster` library. Example:

```
# make sure you have the raster library - you might also need rgdal
install.packages(c('raster', 'rgdal'))

# load the raster library
library(raster)

# define file path
shpFile <- "C:/path/to/shape/file.shp"

# load shapefile
shp <- shapefile(shpFile)

# convert SpatialPointsDataFrame to data.frame
shpDF <- as.data.frame(shp)

# get the distance matrix for coordinate sets
distMat <- dist(shpDF[,2:3])

# print results
print(distMat)

          1         2         3
2 192801.33                    
3 261837.21 133653.67          
4 240095.52  60905.06  86724.96
```

By default it will return the euclidean distance between each point in the shapefile. This should be used for data in a projected coordinate system. If you are using a geographic coordinate system, then look into the `distHaversine` function in the `geosphere` library.

Comment: Thanks, I solved using a plugin on excel, but R would surely be fine!

Answer (score 1):

QGIS `Distance matrix` tool has an option to choose `Output matrix type`. You have probably chosen default `Linear (N*k x 3)` type.

There is another type, `Standard (N x T)`, which returns a common style `Distance matrix`.

It is not a triangle (lower half) one, so you may need to edit it using Excel or text editor.